# xpath - select classes after specific text in php

Tags: php, xpath

I would like to find nodes after a specific text inside an HTML page.
The text is `Search results: Hits` and the class I am looking for is successfully found using `//a[contains(@class,"tooltip")]`. I have tried

```
//*[contains(., "Search results: Hits")]/following:://a[contains(@class,"tooltip")]
```

but I do not get the results I was hoping. Actually, I get no results at all. I guess you know why? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `//` before `a` as

```
//*[contains(., "Search results: Hits")]/following::a[contains(@class,"tooltip")]
```